# Remote control a mac without a monitor from PC and fill PCs 3 monitors

Tags: windows, mac, multiple-monitors, remote-control

Having:

1) A windows 7 PC with three 2560x1440 monitors attached (total resolution of 7680x1440 pixels).

2) An OSX 10.8 Mac Mini with no monitor on it.

What software i need in order to remote control my Mac from PC **and fill the three 2560x1440 monitors?**

Speed is important. The computers are connected with Gbit Ethernet.

Comment: You could do they with a xserver and client  (e.g. xming on the windows side)

Comment: Can you please tell me more about how to use xming?

Comment: The X windowing system is the way most unix workstations use for graphics. It is a bit confusing since what we use to think of as the *client* runs what is called the X-*server*. Other then that it is just a graphical shell. You can use an xserver to connect to a client computer, run programs in the client, and display them on your local monitor. However I have zero OS/X experience, so I just add two links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System and http://www.zen6478.zen.co.uk/image/cap7l.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Initiate a Remote Desktop Connection (or equivalent connection) to the Mac, then instead of maximizing the window, stretch it to fill the entire screen area.

Comment: This (if possible) will just scale the image.

Comment: If the Mac is headless, you may be able to adjust the resolution to match your local resolution.

Comment: I tried but the max resolution mac allowed was 1680x1080... I downloaded a software on the mac and I managed to set the resolution  needed. The thing is, how to add 2 virtual monitors to mac?

Comment: Hmm...looks like it's not possible with the Mini.  I apologize.